# Generic Methods and Bounded Type Parameters

Tags: java, generics

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

How to invoke this method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

I have tried various ways but failed. Excuse me I cannot type more words as Iam using mobile phone. PC is blocked in china.

Comment: for the first parameter, you can pass in any array where the elements of that array implement the `Comparable<T>` interface and for the second parameter make sure you pass a value of the same type as those in the provided array.

Comment: What code have you used to try to invoke the method?  How is it failing?

Comment: countGreaterThan(new Integer[]{1,2,3},Integer.valueOf(2));

Comment: `countGreaterThan(new Integer[]{1,2,3},Integer.valueOf(2));` compiles just fine.

Comment: its ok now. turns out to be an interface named comparable defined in my class.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
Integer arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
Integer n = 2;
int result = countGreaterThan(arr, n);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: this does not compile

Comment: It does compile. Put it in `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire class?

Comment: @Chenxi, I'm glad. Good luck, friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test.countGreaterThan(new String[]{"a", "b"}, "a");
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
        int count = 0;
        for (T e : anArray)
            if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
                ++count;
        return count;
    }
}
```

You can pass anything that implements `Comparable` interface.

e.g. out-of-the-box types are: `Integer`, `Long`, `String`, etc.

You can create your own type which implements `Comparable` and it will be ok for that method.